# SQL Server 2016 Stored Procedure Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I recently restored a SQL Server 2008 database into an instance of SQL Server 2016. Most of the functionality seems to work fine, but many of my stored procedures that include updates to an application database table called SYS_USER fails with the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SYS_USERupdate, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect Syntax near '@errorNumber'

The database does not have a stored procedure called `SYS_Userupdate` and none of the procedures' code includes the term `@errorNumber`. I attempted to run the SQL query from one of the failing procedures directly in SQL Server Management Studio and received the same error message. Here is the SQL query that is failing:

```
UPDATE SYS_USER
SET SYS_USER_LGF_DT = GETDATE()
WHERE SYS_USER_ID = @SYS_USER_ID
```

I plugged in a valid value for the `@SYS_USER_ID` variable. Similar queries in related to other tables run without an issue. All of the stored procedures work on a SQL Server 2008 instance with no errors. Also, the database `compatibility_level` to 100, which should be acceptable for SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Check for triggers on the `SYS_USER` table. (Also, regardless of origin, `sp_helptext 'SYS_USERupdate'` should give you the definition.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert There are triggers on the table, which I did not know before (inherited this database). I will tinker around with these and see if modifying or disabling the triggers will help. Thanks!

Comment: Search for `RAISERROR`. There is a change in syntax for this. Think `2008` is the last version that supports the old format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting the answer since it was proposed in a comment to the question. The solution to the problem was that there were triggers on the affected tables that I did not know were there. Syntax errors on these triggers were causing insert and update queries on the tables to fail.

Credit to Jeroen Mostert https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert for helping with this!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you're not running on a correct version of SQL Server, or if the compatibility level of the database isn't set sufficiently. So change it to 130

To check compatibility level:

```
select compatibility_level 
from sys.databases 
where name = '<database name>'
```

To alter compatibility level:

```
alter database <database-name> 
set compatibility level = 130 -- SQL Server 2016
```

Compatibility levels list for all SQL versions: [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks, @CR241, I will try this along with taking a look at the table triggers as suggested in the comments to the question!